# Mediawiki open external links in a new window

Tags: mediawiki

I want to enable opening external links in a new window function in Mediawiki. I tried to modify the "LocalSettings.php" file according to the below instructions:

```
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Opening_external_links_in_a_new_window
```

But I still couldn't get it working. When I looked up in the above link "Discussion" wiki page I found more informations which confused me. Any idea how to set this work in a simple and straightforward way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to open all external links in new windows (tabs) or only select links.

If it's the latter, then you can try [our new window links extension](http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/NewWindowLinks). Not necessarily pretty, but will work if you only need a few links.

Now, if you want *all* external links to open up in new windows, you need to use the [LinkerMakeExternalLink hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LinkerMakeExternalLink) and modify the `$attribs` parameter to your liking.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 9):

- **If you want a few specific links to open in a new window:**
  You can use the [LinkTarget extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LinkTarget). You can then surround the appropriate links with an HTML element with a class of your choosing and get the extension to handle them.

  ([tor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881963/932484) also had a relevant extension linked, but Wikia removed that extension and it probably will not be maintained).
- **If you want *all* external links to open in a new window:**
  MediaWiki already has a setting for it: *$wgExternalLinkTarget*.
  Just add the following to your *LocalSettings.php* file:

  ```
  $wgExternalLinkTarget = '_blank';
  ```

  Do keep in mind that some internal links might not be identified as such, and therefore will open in a new window; one such example is an internal edit link created by using

  ```
  [{{fullurl:Main Page|action=edit}}]
  ```

Link: [$wgExternalLinkTarget on MediaWiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgExternalLinkTarget)